# Fetch currently logged in user relation with a given model instance

Tags: mysql, django, performance, django-models

Assume we have a model called Author as such:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

We also have a feature which enables users to follow a certain author:

```
class UserFollow(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

If you have a button in your UI that enables logged in users to follow / unfollow these authors. One way to check if this user is already following a certain author is to make a query on the existence of a record in UserFollow. However, when you're fetching a list of 10 / 20 .. etc authors, how would you check each author for the currently logged in user?

The usual approach would result in +X number of extra queries depending on how many items you're loading per page. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same effect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch all instances of `UserFollow` in view, pass it as a variable to the template and then you can check if given author is in this list

```
def my_view(request):
    following = list(UserFollow.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    template_context = {
        'following': following
    }
```

template:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {% if author in following %}
        {# do some magic #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```